# PHP Encrypting Larger Files

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt all files being uploaded to the server, and my method of doing it works; but I've noticed DECRYPTING files over 100kb just returns null, and I'm confused why encrypting works on these files, but decrypting doesn't. Is there something wrong with my code, or is there another approach to this? There is nothing wrong with the allowed upload sizes in php.ini, the upload.php page works perfectly fine, and uploads the files to the server. The only issue is with files over 100kb. I have a feeling it has something to do with the max variable length in PHP, but I'm not sure.

```
// Encrypt Function
public static function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key)
{
    $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
    return $encoded;
}

// Decrypt Function
public static function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key)
{
    $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt.'|');
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
    if(strlen($iv)!==mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)){ return false; }
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
    $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Where it should be decrypted:

```
try
    {
        $server = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerIP` = :ip LIMIT 1");
        $server->execute([ ":ip" => $ip ]);
        $server = $server->fetch();
        $sftp = new SFTPConnection($server['ServerIP'], intval($server['ServerPort']));
        $sftp->login($server['ServerUser'], $server['ServerPassword']);
        $fileData = $sftp->receiveFile($path);

        //print $fileData;

        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        $fileName = $file['FileName'];
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");

        //print $fileData; (returns the encrypted version)
        $fileData = Encryption::mc_decrypt($fileData, $file['EncryptionKey']);

        print $fileData; // (returns null on larger files)
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: First, figure out which of the two `return false` is actually triggered.

Comment: It's failing here: if(strlen($iv)!==mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)){ return "failed"; }

Comment: You probably do not want `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`, the `256` is the block size which is not the AES block size, it is not the key size.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that **can't be used with binary data**. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @sunguM Hm, this would mean you're in a multibyte environment. Have you tried to use `mb_strlen` instead? Have you checked that the same issue happens when you encrypt and decrypt without the SFTP code (I mean locally)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I first voted up your comment, but as the `strlen` function of PHP returns the size of the IV *in bytes, including zero valued bytes* I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, decrypting and encrypting strings / files locally works perfectly fine (same issue with larger files). From reading the other comments, I'm assuming I should just use another encrypting algorithm?

Comment: @sunguM If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I do know a solution. First of all, you probably want to read in the file in chucks. You don't want to store e.g. an entire movie in RAM. So what you can do is to treat the SFTP connection as stream:

According to the sample code here:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'rb');
```

Note that I used `'rb'` to force binary mode.

So now you can read in chunks from the stream, the only thing you need to do is to encrypt/decrypt the stream. [Mcrypt does actually provide this functionality using a filter implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.encryption.php).

As for the HMAC, [you can stream that as well](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php). You may want to [create a filter for it](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.filters.php) - I could not find one.

So now that you can stream everything, go ahead and implement it.

---

Security notes:

- mcrypt is an old library that should not be used anymore;
- use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 instead of using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 if you want to use AES (the 256 is the block size, not the key size, the key size is determined by - wait for it - the size of the provided key);
- HMAC is secure, but it should be performed over the ciphertext and the IV;
- this is not a full transport protocol - but that doesn't matter much if you send the file over sftp.